# Python: Pretty print json file with array ID's

Tags: python, json, cisco

I would like to pretty print a json file where i can see the array ID's. Im working on a Cisco Nexus Switch with NX-OS that runs Python (2.7.11). Looking at following code:

```
    cmd = 'show interface Eth1/1 counters'
    out = json.loads(clid(cmd))
    print (json.dumps(out, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

This gives me:

```
{
    "TABLE_rx_counters": {
        "ROW_rx_counters": [
            {
                "eth_inbytes": "442370508663", 
                "eth_inucast": "76618907", 
                "interface_rx": "Ethernet1/1"
            }, 
            {
                "eth_inbcast": "4269", 
                "eth_inmcast": "49144", 
                "interface_rx": "Ethernet1/1"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "TABLE_tx_counters": {
        "ROW_tx_counters": [
            {
                "eth_outbytes": "217868085254", 
                "eth_outucast": "66635610", 
                "interface_tx": "Ethernet1/1"
            }, 
            {
                "eth_outbcast": "1137", 
                "eth_outmcast": "557815", 
                "interface_tx": "Ethernet1/1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But i need to access the field by:

```
rxuc = int(out['TABLE_rx_counters']['ROW_rx_counters'][0]['eth_inucast'])
rxmc = int(out['TABLE_rx_counters']['ROW_rx_counters'][1]['eth_inmcast'])
rxbc = int(out['TABLE_rx_counters']['ROW_rx_counters'][1]['eth_inbcast'])
txuc = int(out['TABLE_tx_counters']['ROW_tx_counters'][0]['eth_outucast'])
txmc = int(out['TABLE_tx_counters']['ROW_tx_counters'][1]['eth_outmcast'])
txbc = int(out['TABLE_tx_counters']['ROW_tx_counters'][1]['eth_outbcast'])
```

So i need to know the array ID (in this example zeros and ones) to access the information for this interface. It seems pretty easy with only 2 arrays, but imagine 500. Right now, i always copy the json code to jsoneditoronline.org where i can see the ID's:

[image]

Is there an easy way to make the IDs visible within python itself?

Comment: The JSON syntax does not allow for array indexes to be printed. Doing so would make the JSON invalid / unparsable. What you could do is walking through those arrays and adding another field (e.g. `index`) to the elements that contains the index.

Comment: Well i wont change the json structure of the 'out' variable itslef, I only want to change the printed structure.

Comment: Well, what you posted is valid JSON. The image is from a tool that takes the data from JSON and displays it. You can display it in any way you want, but the contents in the file will need to be valid JSON. If you do not need to load the JSON later, you can do with it whatever you like, but `json.dumps` will give you JSON only.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. Can you put in an aswer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted is valid JSON.
The image is from a tool that takes the data from JSON and displays it. You can display it in any way you want, but the contents in the file will need to be valid JSON.

If you do not need to load the JSON later, you can do with it whatever you like, but `json.dumps()` will give you JSON only.